# How to set background image as fixed for android 4.x with phonegap?

Tags: android, css, cordova, android-emulator

I am developing an android application with phonegap 2.0. I debug my application with ripple addon which runs on google chrome. Everything is ok on ripple but on android not. On android, background image does not fixed. I have made tons of search on google but I could not find any solution.

MY css is:

```
background-image: url('../img/hdpi/App_Bg.png') !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-size: 100% 100% !important;
background-position:100% 100% !important;
```

How can I set the background image as fixed for android webkit browser? Is there any magic solution?

Comment: only if you could tell the meaning of fixing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included these meta tags?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no", ,height=device-height/>
<meta name="layout" content="mobile"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```